# How can I import and use Function from another file Inside API Server file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

I am using ReactJS & Firebase & React Redux

https://github.com/oguzdelioglu/reactPress

I am showing data in Firestore by calling Functions in https://github.com/oguzdelioglu/reactPress/blob/master/src/services/firebase/index.js File in Components

I want to send data to Firestore by adding API Server to this project.

So I created an API Server with NodeJS & Express.
https://github.com/oguzdelioglu/reactPress/blob/master/src/services/server/index.js

I will add data to Firestore in response to the incoming POST request.

I will send the data sent by POST to the firestore using the addPost function in the index.js file, but when I import this function in server/index.js, I encounter an error.

import { addPost } from '../index.js' 
When I import it this way, I get an error as follows.

```
(node:30644) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\kemer\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react\src\services\server\index.js:2
import { addPost } from '../index.js'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

const { addPost } = require('../index.js');
When I use it this way, I get an error as follows.

```
C:\Users\kemer\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react\src\services\firebase.js:1
import store from '../stores/index.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kemer\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react\src\services\server\index.js:1:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

I want to be able to use addPost function in index.js file in server/index.js.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
const store = require('../stores/index.js');
```

This is because you're not using latest version of Javascript

Comment: When I use it this way, the problem is not solved. On the contrary, the codes I use for Redux Toolkit are also corrupted.